# How many Android devices support GLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause today?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I don't need the exact number, the percentage would be enough.
For example, if I develop an app with 4.0 min SDK version, how can I assure that the context will be preserved? May it depend on the OpenGL-ES version?

I tried to find information about chips with limited EGL context but couldn't find any.

The reason I need to know - I don't want to implement a special cache subsystem which will reload my textures after the app is resumed. I'm ready to drop some devices that don't support preserving the context (if less than 5-7%).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that OpenGL-ES 2.0 and forward all allow multiple EGL contexts. That is what the `GLSurfaceView.GLThreadManager.checkGLESVersion()` method assumes. And if you have multiple contexts, it is not necessary to terminate the EGL when pausing, neither release the EGL context when pausing.

Also, from the `GLSurfaceView.GLThreadManager` source code (around line 1908), we have the following comment, just after the `checkGLESVersion()` method:

```
// This check was required for some pre-Android-3.0 hardware. 
// Android 3.0 provides support for hardware-accelerated views, 
// therefore multiple EGL contexts are supported on all Android 3.0+ EGL drivers.
```

See more details at Grepcode [GLSurfaceView.GLThreadManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java#GLSurfaceView.GLThreadManager.shouldReleaseEGLContextWhenPausing%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

since API function is level 11 so Honeycomb. its 94.0% of devices according to Android Site
[Android Platform versions](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone)

Comment: I know that this method appeared in API level 11 and I can call it. Right.
But according to docs 
"If set to true, then the EGL context **may** be preserved"
So "may" means that there is no guarantee. Am I wrong?