# How to know if a device can support multiple EGL contexts?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

i want to set setPreserveEGLContextOnPause to true, but from the android help we can read :

setPreserveEGLContextOnPause
Control whether the EGL context is preserved when the GLSurfaceView is paused and resumed. If set to true, then the EGL context **may be** preserved when the GLSurfaceView is paused. **Whether the EGL context is actually preserved or not depends upon whether the Android device that the program is running on can support an arbitrary number of EGL contexts or not**. Devices that can only support a limited number of EGL contexts must release the EGL context in order to allow multiple applications to share the GPU.

So setPreserveEGLContextOnPause will only work if the device can support multiple EGL contexts. But how to know this ?

Comment: Note that this is phenomenally bad practice for any app using large amounts of graphics resources (you simply end up reserving a lot of system memory for background applications), and is likely to end up with your applications being hard-killed by the system when it runs low on resources.

I'd highly recommend playing nicely with context suspend and resume if you can ....

Comment: i think that a phenomenally bad practic is to keep in memory the copy of the bits of you image to be able to recreate is after the context was lost => resulting in using 2x more memory :(

Comment: If you're getting backgrounded just store the bits you need to keep to the file system (your app may well get killed if the foreground app needs more memory, so most apps want some form of disk-based persistence to cope with this anyway).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many Android devices support GLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause today?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068726/how-many-android-devices-support-glsurfaceview-setpreserveeglcontextonpause-toda)